# How to specify InternalName for a list field in Sharepoint Client Object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

I'm trying to add a field to my current list. This is what I've achieved so far:

```
Field description = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
                    @"<Field Type='Note' Name='DataType'
                             DisplayName='Data Type' NumLines='6'/>",
                    true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
                    description.Update();
```

I want the **DataType** to be internalName and the **Data Type** to be my display name. Just want to confirm if this is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NadeemYousuf. So Name='DataType' specifies the internam name for my field. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
Field description = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
                @"<Field Type='Note' Name='DataType'
                         DisplayName='Data Type' NumLines='6'/>",
                true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
```

If you don't specify Field option parameter `AddFieldInternalNameHint`, the internal name will be generated based on `DisplayName`.